# Select Most Recent date

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT     dbo.Team.ID, dbo.Team.Comment, dbo.Team.Date, dbo.TeamName.Name, dbo.Contacts.ContactName 
FROM       dbo.Team 
INNER JOIN dbo.TeamName ON dbo.Team.ID = dbo.TeamName.id 
INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts ON dbo.Team.ContactID = dbo.Contacts.ContactID   
WHERE      dbo.TeamName.idstatus = 'Active'
```

I am trying to query it in a way that it only gives me records with most recent date but it is getting little confusing because I am already pulling data from 3 tables and not sure how to use `MAX(date)` here.

Comment: Can you show some sample data and desired results? What you're trying to do is a little confusing to us, too. Are you trying to get one row per team? What does `Team.Date` represent - `Date` of WHAT? Shouldn't you name your columns a little better? Also why do you store team name in a separate table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT     dbo.Team.ID, dbo.Team.Comment, MAX(dbo.Team.Date) LatestDate, dbo.TeamName.Name, dbo.Contacts.ContactName 
FROM       dbo.Team 
INNER JOIN dbo.TeamName ON dbo.Team.ID = dbo.TeamName.id 
INNER JOIN dbo.Contacts ON dbo.Team.ContactID = dbo.Contacts.ContactID   
WHERE      dbo.TeamName.idstatus = 'Active'
GROUP BY   dbo.Team.ID, dbo.Team.Comment, dbo.TeamName.Name, dbo.Contacts.ContactName
```

ADDING MAX() Function to your date column and group by all the columns with you the Latest date for the combination of values in all other columns.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to filter by `dbo.Team.Date`.

Change your `WHERE` clause to:

```
WHERE (dbo.TeamName.idstatus = 'Active') 
and (dbo.Team.Date=(select max(Date) from dbo.Team))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use GroupBy and Having:

```
SELECT     dbo.Team.ID, dbo.Team.Comment, MAX(dbo.Team.Date), dbo.TeamName.Name,   dbo.Contacts.ContactName, 
FROM         dbo.Team 
INNER JOIN
dbo.TeamName ON dbo.Team.ID = dbo.TeamName.id 
INNER JOIN
dbo.Contacts ON dbo.Team.ContactID = dbo.Contacts.ContactID
WHERE     (dbo.TeamName.idstatus = 'Active')
GROUP BY dbo.Team.ID, dbo.Team.Comment, dbo.Team.Date, dbo.TeamName.Name, dbo.Contacts.ContactName
HAVING dbo.Team.Date = MAX(dbo.Team.Date)
```